# Creating a link to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, bookmarklet

I'd like to link to a specific button that is activated with js.
[Here is the page](http://hornbeckoffshore.com/fleet/featured/hos-accommodation-support-fleet/hosmpsv-flotel/hos-achiever) 
Right now the "Base Vessel" image collection (bottom of page) is displayed when opening the page.
I want to be able to display directly "Fitness center" image collection instead whith my link and also scroll down. 
Is this possible to code this in a link?

Comment: From *within* the page?  You would write JavaScript code in the link's click handler to do whatever clicking that "Fitness center" element does.  From *outside* the page?  Not without modifying the page's code, no.  You can't put code in a simple URL.  What you can do is include values in the URL, which code on the page itself can look for and respond to.  You'd need to modify the code on the page to check the URL values when it loads and perform the action you want it to perform.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it's from outside the page, I want to put a link in my website that goes to that specific part of the target website.
Here is my website page 
http://marinevisuals.com/achiever-gym
and the link I'm trying to change is at the top: "  Click here to see the actual Gym."
Thanks anyway.